# Prevent a file descriptor's closure on POSIX systems

Tags: python, c, unix, posix, system-calls

There is a library (libvte, a terminal emulation library) that uses a pair of file descriptors for a pty master/slave pair.  I need to be able to "steal" the master fd from the library for my own use (in order to implement support for ZMODEM for the very rare occasion when the only link I have to the 'net is via a terminal).  However, there is a problem.

You can tell libvte that you want to change the file descriptor to a new one, but then it attempts to close the master that it is using, and start using the new one instead.  This won't work, because when the master is closed the slave goes away.  Originally, I thought that it would be possible to use `dup()` on the pty master, such that when libvte did `close()` on the PTY master, I'd still have a functioning fd to use.  That is apparently wrong.

I need to find a way to either:

- Block libvte's `read()` operations on the fd.
- Steal the fd away from libvte until I'm doing using it (e.g., until the `rz` process that I am connecting it to exits)

Is it possible on a POSIX system to do either of these things?  Or would there be some other way to accomplish the same thing without patching libvte itself?  The reason that I ask is that the solution has to work on a fair number of existing systems.

If it is at all relevant, I'm interfacing with libvte (and GTK+ itself) via Python.  However, I'd not be averse to writing a Python extension in C that I could then call from a Python program, because you don't have to be privileged on any system to load a Python extension.

If none of it is possible, I may be forced to fork libvte to do what I want it to do and distribute that with my program, but I don't want to do that --- I do not want to be stuck maintaining a fork!

Comment: don't you want to tag with with Python, or C ? Good Luck!

Comment: I would, but the question is really agnostic to both, I think... if I tag "C", people would be likely to say that it's really not a C question, it's a Python question (being the target environment and all); if I tag Python, they're likely to say that this is really a C-level or system-call level issue... not really sure what to do!

Comment: just that for people that check for 'their' specialty by language may never see your question. I would go with 'C' because that is (almost certainly) the underlying language of POSIX. Compared to 'file-descriptor' ? ;-) ? You can always change it to Python in a day or 2 if you don't get any answers. I include 'C' in my standard 'check S.O.' and the strength in answers I see on obscure questions is humbling ;-) Good Luck!

Comment: Could you be more specific about why your `dup` plan failed?  Because I think it should work.  Also, could you not prevent libvte from touching the descriptor simply by not making any calls to libvte?

Comment: As best as I can tell, `dup` says to duplicate the fd exactly.  The new fd shares all of the characteristics—position, etc.—as the first.  I didn't think that applied to closing, but it appears to do so; as soon as the first fd is closed, the `dup()`'d fd is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution would be to write a helper process which opens its own pty master/slave pair, and interposes between `libvte` and the actual target program that runs on the slave pty:

```
+---------------+
| libvte        |
|               |
|    pty master=|-----\
+---------------+     |
                      |
+---------------+     |
| helper proxy  |     |
|               |     |
|  stdin/stdout=|-----/
|               |
|    pty master=|-----\
+---------------+     |
                      |
+---------------+     |
| target        |     |
|               |     |
|  stdin/stdout=|-----/
+---------------+
```

Your helper process normally just passes through data, until it sees ZMODEM traffic.  It then stops passing data to `stdin` / `stdout` (which winds up at `libvte`) and instead either passes it to your application through a separate file descriptor, or even just invokes `rz` itself.

Answer (score 1):

`dup()`'d file descriptors are not affected by `close()` calls of other instances; however, it's possible libvte may be calling some other shutdown methods which do change its state. Use `strace` to investigate in more detail.

Apart from that, there are a few things you can do, but none of them are very pretty. One option would be to replace the file descriptor from under libvte. That is:

- First, use `dup()` to get your own copy of the fd, and stash it somewhere
- Use `dup2()` to overwrite libvte's fd with one of your own choosing. This should be a new pty with a configuration similar to that of the one you're stealing, to avoid confusing libvte. Since you'll never write anything to the other end, reads will block (you'll need to do something with any data libvte may write down there!)
- If libvte may be in a blocking `read()` at that very moment, send a signal to its thread (with a no-op - *not* SIGIGN - handler) to interrupt the `read()` call.
- Do your work with the fd you duplicated at the start
- To return to normal, use `dup2()` to put the fd back, then copy any pty state changes libvte may have made to the original descriptor.

Alternately, you can do as caf suggests, and simply have a proxy pty in there from the start.